# QueryPath Find - Finding elements using multiple selectors

Tags: php, css-selectors, querypath

What I am trying to achieve is finding both the UL and DIV in the following example. Aswell as any other possible subsequent DIVs and ULs.

```
<ul id="networknavigation" class="navigation" role="navigation">
</ul>
[ .. some code .. ]
<div id="footer" class="navigation">
</div>
[ .. some code .. ]
```

After taking a look at the QueryPath API I found out that it was possible to use multiple selectors as you can see in the "Example selectors" part of the page:
[QueryPath CSS Selector Reference](http://api.querypath.org/docs/_c_s_s_reference.html)

I am working with PHP and QueryPath using a function like this:

```
public function testFindNavigation()
{
 $errors = array();
 foreach($this->qp->find('ul, div') as $el) {
    if($el->hasClass('navigation, nav, menu') || $el->attr('id') == 'nav' || $el->attr('role') == 'navigation') {
      array_push($errors, $el->html());
    }
 }
 return $errors; 
}
```

Unfortunately, this function only returns the UL and not the footer-DIV and I can't really why it is not working. I also tried to use the find method like this:

```
qp->find('ul', 'div')
```

This gives me the exact same result.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to change

```
$el->hasClass('navigation, nav, menu')
```

to

```
$el->hasClass('navigation', 'nav', 'menu')
```

The reason that only ULs are being returned is that your version of the above statement is asking if the element has the class "navigation, nav, menu", which is not what you intented.

Comment: I already tried the version with seperated strings, same result.
The [QueryPath Find reference](http://api.querypath.org/docs/class_query_path.html#a3dee7b848a27c58364868af549e14daa) states that it only takes a string as an argument.

Also find shouldn't return anything at all if I was looking for an element with class set to "navigation, nav, menu".

Comment: Are you sure?  The way your "or" statement reads, you would still get results from anything with the role navigation wouldn't you? Also, the reference I read only showed a single class in the argument -- what if you separate the classes into $el->hasClass('navigation') || $el->hasClass('nav') || $el->hasClass('menu') ?